# Monorail cannot read JSON (a list of objects) data received from jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-monorail

I have the following jquery ajax:

```
 $(".gridster ul").gridster({
               widget_margins: [5, 5],
               widget_base_dimensions: [280, 280],
               draggable: {
                stop: function(event, ui){ 
                              var orderState = {
        photos:  $(".gridster ul").data("gridster").serialize(),
        promoid: $.getUrlVar('promoId')
        };
       $.ajax({
                url: "/Photos/SetOrder",
                data: {neworder:orderState},
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST'
            });
```

Which I send to a Monorail 2.1 controller.

The orderState object from JS looks likes this:

```
neworder[photos][0][height]=1
neworder[photos][0][id]=98315
neworder[photos][0][width]=1
neworder[photos][0][x]=2
neworder[photos][0][y]=1
neworder[photos][1][height]=1
neworder[photos][1][id]=98316
neworder[photos][1][width]=1
neworder[photos][1][x]=1
neworder[photos][1][y]=1
neworder[photos][2][height]=1
neworder[photos][2][id]=98317
neworder[photos][2][width]=1
neworder[photos][2][x]=1
neworder[photos][2][y]=2
neworder[photos][3][height]=1
neworder[photos][3][id]=98318
neworder[photos][3][width]=1
neworder[photos][3][x]=1
neworder[photos][3][y]=3
neworder[promoid]=163844
```

And it should map to the following c# viewmodel class:

```
 public class OrderViewModel
    {
        public int height { get; set; }

        public int width { get; set; }

        public int x { get; set; }

        public int y { get; set; }

        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewPromoImageOrderViewModel
    {
        public NewPromoImageOrderViewModel()
        {
            Photos = new List<OrderViewModel>();
        }

        public int PromoId { get; set; }

        public List<OrderViewModel> Photos { get; set; }
    }
```

Used by the following action:

```
  [return: JSONReturnBinder]
        [AccessibleThrough(Verb.Post)]
        public object SetOrder([JSONBinder("neworder")] NewPromoImageOrderViewModel neworder)
        {
            //bla
        }
```

And the response it gives me is this:

> Message: Error building method arguments. Last param analyzed was
>   neworder with value ''
>
> StackTrace:    at
>   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.SmartDispatcherController.BuildMethodArguments(ParameterInfo[]
>   parameters, IRequest request, IDictionary`2 actionArgs) in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Monorail\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\MR2\src\Castle.MonoRail.Framework\SmartDispatcherController.cs:line
>   329    at
>   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.SmartDispatcherController.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo
>   method, IRequest request, IDictionary`2 extraArgs) in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Monorail\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\MR2\src\Castle.MonoRail.Framework\SmartDispatcherController.cs:line
>   80    at
>   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.ActionMethodExecutorCompatible.Execute(IEngineContext
>   engineContext, IController controller, IControllerContext context) in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Monorail\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\MR2\src\Castle.MonoRail.Framework\ActionMethodExecutor.cs:line
>   79    at Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Controller.RunActionAndRenderView()
>   in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Monorail\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\MR2\src\Castle.MonoRail.Framework\Controller.cs:line 1639
>
> Inner exception: ArgumentNullException
>
> Message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s
>
> StackTrace:    at System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type)
>   at
>   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Services.NewtonsoftJSONSerializer.Deserialize(String
>   jsonString, Type expectedType) in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Monorail\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\MR2\src\Castle.MonoRail.Framework\Services\NewtonsoftJSONSerializer.cs:line
>   100    at
>   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.JSONBinderAttribute.Bind(IEngineContext
>   context, IController controller, IControllerContext controllerContext,
>   ParameterInfo parameterInfo) in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Monorail\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\MR2\src\Castle.MonoRail.Framework\Attributes\JSONBinderAttribute.cs:line
>   135    at
>   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.SmartDispatcherController.BuildMethodArguments(ParameterInfo[]
>   parameters, IRequest request, IDictionary`2 actionArgs) in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Monorail\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\MR2\src\Castle.MonoRail.Framework\SmartDispatcherController.cs:line
>   288

I'm pretty sure my mappings and viewmodel class are correct. JQuery does send the expected json object, but Monorail seems to have problems converting it. Could this be a bug?

EDIT:Well, Monorail wasn't at fault at here... The things i put through the post WERENT A JSON after all. After using this library: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/, I managed to convert the object to JSON. I thought that by choosing the dataType:"json" would have been enough, but apparently it's not.

Comment: is it definitely an object not a string? `dataType: 'json'` should always force it but I've seen situations when it doesn't

Comment: how do i know if it's an object or not? When I switched to a JSON object made out of hand picked primitive values, likes {first:1, second:"adad"}, and changed the code on the server side, Monorail parsed the parameters correctly. I think it's an object.

Comment: on a browser you would use `console.log`, if it's expandable it's an object, if it's just shown as a string it's a string. In code you would use a function like `is_object()` or `typeof`, whatever the function is in c#.

Comment: If I put orderState in the console log, it appears as expandable, when I enumerate throught the list of photos.

Comment: Also, I've checked if the JSON object is really an object, and yeah, it is (using a is_object function() from the web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype option in the $.ajax call refers to the data that is expected. What you need to do is this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Photos/SetOrder",  
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: JSON.stringify({neworder:orderState}),
  type: 'POST'
});
```